# php why is basic super global failing?

Tags: php, global-variables

i am using globals to share variables between functions like this

```
<?php
$whatyear;
$whatfirstname;
$whatlastname;
function mycustom_user_register_submit($form, &$form_state)
{
            $GLOBALS["whatyear"]=$form_state['values']['yearofstudy'];
            $GLOBALS["whatfirstname"]=$form_state['values']['firstname'];
            $GLOBALS["whatlastname"]=$form_state['values']['lastname'];
}
function course_registration_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category)
{
            $newuserid=$account->uid;
            $yearofstudy=$GLOBALS["whatyear"];
            $fname=$GLOBALS["whatfirstname"];
            $lname=$GLOBALS["whatlastname"];
                        //now use vars
                        drupal_set_message('dear '.$fname.' '.$lname.' ,'.'account uid is '.$account->uid); 
}
```

But the variables

> fname,lname,yearofstudy

are shockingly empty! please help me figure out why. 
am getting errors like

```
Notice: Undefined index: whatyear in course_registration_user_insert() (line 110 of C:\wamp\www\drupal-7.1\sites\all\modules\course_registration\course_registration.module).
```

Comment: Please add more detail. The variables you say are empty don't show in your code above. Also it's impossible to say what happens without knowing whether `$form_state` actually contains anything

Comment: Are we to assume you are in fact calling the `mycustom_user_register_submit()` function before calling the `course_registration_user_insert()` function?

Comment: @Pekka - See the next-to-last line starting with `drupal_set_message(`.

Comment: @Pekka:The variables appear in drupal_set_message() function. Also, deleting the second function and adding this to first function makes stuff work    drupal_set_message('your variables are '.$GLOBALS["whatyear"]."....".$GLOBALS["whatfirstname"]." ..... ".$GLOBALS["whatlastname"]);

Comment: full code at http://pastebin.com/Rt8SPaVz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using global variables like this:

```
<?php
function mycustom_user_register_submit($form, &$form_state)
{
    global $whatyear;
    global $whatfirstname;
    global $whatlastname;
    $whatyear=$form_state['values']['yearofstudy'];
    $whatfirstname=$form_state['values']['firstname'];
    $whatlastname=$form_state['values']['lastname'];
}
function course_registration_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category)
{
    global $whatyear;
    global $whatfirstname;
    global $whatlastname;
    $newuserid=$account->uid;
    $yearofstudy=$whatyear;
    $fname=$whatfirstname;
    $lname=$whatlastname;
    //now use vars
    drupal_set_message('dear '.$fname.' '.$lname.' ,'.'account uid is '.$account->uid); 
}
?>
```

If this doesn't work, make sure these functions are called in the same php instance in the right order. If the first one is called on one page, and then insert is called on another page, a new copy of php will be opened, and you will lose your environment variables.

Comment: Shouldn't make any difference. Using `$GLOBALS` should work fine

Comment: Is there any way you can show where the functions are being called?

Comment: @ xthexder :am using drupal http://drupal.org/. As long as my functions are named in a particular way, drupal calls them for me. In this case the my fns are hooks called by drupal. But the question was about php , not drupal